# Masstransit: Can not run code from within Visual Studio (QueueNotFound)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, msmq, masstransit

I'm trying to run some sample code from the MassTransit project:

```
var bus = ServiceBusFactory.New(sbc =>
{
    sbc.UseMsmq().Validate();
    sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/app1_queue");
    sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();

     sbc.Subscribe(s=>
     {
        s.Handler<CustomMessage>(msg => { Console.WriteLine(msg.Body); });
     });
});
```

When I now just `F5` in Visual Studio, I get the following exception:

```
MessageQueueException: The queue does not exist or you do not have
sufficient permissions to perform the operation.
MessageQueueErrorCode: System.Messaging.MessageQueueErrorCode.QueueNotFound
```

I checked the MessageQueues in the Management Console, and indeed see that the queue is not there.
However, if I run the TestApp1.exe, everything works fine and queues are created. Back to Visual Studio, still the same error (but queues are now available.)

I've tried setting the security of the queues (Everyone full access), but it doesn't change.

What am I doing wrong? Why can I not run this from within Visual Studio?

**EDIT**

I've installed `RabbitMQ` and updated the code:

```
sbc.UseRabbitMq();
sbc.ReceiveFrom("rabbitmq://localhost/app1_queue");
```

and it works.
Question remains: what is wrong with msmq? I would prefer to keep using that.

Comment: I would suggest using RabbitMQ over MSMQ regardless, it's a lot more powerful. The problem is likely permissions - that's the exception the MSMQ libraries return. Are you running Visual Studio as Admin? What version of MT (latest from NuGet?) and OS are you running? I would also join the mailing list to get faster responses than here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/masstransit-discuss

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem ?

Comment: Nope. Using RabbitMQ instead. It has a few advantages over MSMQ, also practically: installation and distribution of RabbitMQ is much easier than MSMQ.

Answer (score 1):

Accessing and operating MSMQ is subject to Windows authorization (and UAC). Unless you run VS with elevated  privileges you may not have the permissions. I'm not sure about the specifics, but try granting your account rights to create and modify the queues.

Comment: could you explain in more detail how to grant your account rights ?